# onClickListener not working on searchview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, searchview

I've a searchview with background. I wanted to implement a click listener. But the onClickListener only firing when i click on the magnifying icon not on the query area. if i use onQueryTextListener then its not working for magnifying glass icon.

How do i implement click listener so that when i click anywhere on the search view clicklistener should be triggered.

[searchview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqL3O.png)

**Searchview :**

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="46dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/search_view_background"
    android:submitBackground="@drawable/search_view_background"
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    app:defaultQueryHint="@string/search"
    app:queryBackground="@null"
    app:queryHint="@string/search" >
</androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>
```

**background :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/search_background"/>
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

**MainActivity**

```
searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"search",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            loadFragment(searchResultsFragment);
        }
    });
```

Comment: One option is to add a `setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener`. It will fire if you will click on the text field. But it will fire only when the focus changes.

Comment: @HaykMkrtchyan this actually worked with has focus parameter. but not working for magnifying glass icon. Thanks . I can make it work

Comment: Yeah for the magnify icon you need that click listener in your code